# Get 101 (reset connection) error when connect to the remote jupyter via browser (ssh tunnel established via Putty)

Tags: jupyter, remote-access, putty

I run jupyter on remote machine, establish ssh tunnel via putty and can't connect from local machine, because I get 101 error. How to fix it?